# Pandas Dataframe - Generate incremental values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

In my workflow there are multiple CSVs with four columns `OID, value, count, unique_id`. I am trying to figure how to generate incremental values under `unique_id` column. Using `apply()`, I can do something like `df.apply(lambda x : x + 1) #where x = 0` and it will result in all values under `unique_id` as 1. However, I am confused on how to use `apply()` to generate incrementally values in each row for a specific column.

```
# Current Dataframe 
   OID  Value  Count  unique_id
0   -1      1      5          0
1   -1      2     46          0
2   -1      3     32          0
3   -1      4      3          0
4   -1      5     17          0

# Trying to accomplish
   OID  Value  Count  unique_id
0   -1      1      5          0
1   -1      2     46          1
2   -1      3     32          2
3   -1      4      3          3
4   -1      5     17          4
```

Sample code (I understand that the syntax is incorrect, but it is approximately what I am trying to accomplish):

```
def numbers():
    for index, row in RG_Res_df.iterrows():
        return index

RG_Res_df = RG_Res_df['unique_id'].apply(numbers)
```

Comment: you can just do `df['unique_id'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't loop you can just directly assign a numpy array to generate the id, here using [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and pass the num of rows which will be `df.shape[0]`

```
In [113]:
df['unique_id'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
df

Out[113]:
   OID  Value  Count  unique_id
0   -1      1      5          0
1   -1      2     46          1
2   -1      3     32          2
3   -1      4      3          3
4   -1      5     17          4
```

or pure pandas method using `RangeIndex`, here the default `start` is `0` so we only need to pass `stop=df.shape[0]`:

```
In [114]:
df['unique_id'] = pd.RangeIndex(stop=df.shape[0])
df

Out[114]:
   OID  Value  Count  unique_id
0   -1      1      5          0
1   -1      2     46          1
2   -1      3     32          2
3   -1      4      3          3
4   -1      5     17          4
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Is Numpy functions preferred over Pandas? or are they pretty comparable? Also, `df['unique_id'] = pd.RangeIndex(stop=df.shape[0])` gives me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RangeIndex'`. Any idea? I was able to iterate using its index earlier.

Comment: you may need to add `import pandas as pd` also generally there isn't much different but numpy methods will be faster so it should be preferred where it does what you want

Comment: I found the problem, I am using an older version of Pandas at work. Also, could you point why wouldn't the following `np.arange` syntax: `df['unique_id'] = np.arange(57)` throws this error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`?

Comment: Well the error is telling you the lengths are different so what you tried will make an array from 0 to 56 making 57 rows is this correct?

Comment: Sort of. I just realized that I only need to generate the unique values on a select rows from 0 to 56. I assumed that since `np.arange` works much like `range` does in python, so if I were to provide a stop value (i.e. 57) it would only generate values for the said rows where `start=0` by default. Sorry for the confusion!